Do different bases of Fock space commute?
$\newcommand\dag\dagger$
Suppose we have a Fock space $\mathcal{F}$ with two different bases of creation and annihilation operators $\{a_\lambda, a^\dag_\lambda\}$ and $\{a_{\tilde \lambda}, a^\dag_{\tilde \lambda}\}$. The change of basis formula for these operators is given by:
$$
a^\dag_{\tilde \lambda} = \sum_\lambda \langle \lambda | \tilde{\lambda} \rangle a^\dag_\lambda
$$
and similar equations for $a_{\tilde \lambda}$, etc. However, this seems to imply that $a^\dag_{\tilde \lambda}$ and $a^\dag_{\lambda}$ commute or anti-commute (depending on if the space describes bosonic or fermionic particles, respectively). This seems surprising to me, so I had the following two questions:

Is this actually true?
If not, why not? If it is, why should we expect this to be true and is there a physical interpretation/intuition for this?


For any single-particle states $f,g\in\mathfrak h$, we have that $[a(f),a(g)]_\pm=0$, and the same for the creation operators. The sign convention reflects the fermionic/bosonic case.

Commute with respect of what operation? it is a vector space, there is no multiplication defined between the elements of a base, or between any vectors in general

@PatoGalmarini I agree that the title is confusing, but in the body of the post the question is formulated clearly.

Yes, it is true: direct inspection.

For a given decomposition of the Fock space into $n$-particle subspaces, creation operator commute. For a $1$ particle state $|\psi\rangle$, there is an associated annihilation operator $a(\psi)$. If $|\psi\rangle,|\psi'\rangle$ are any two $1$-particle states, then an elementary calculation shows that $a(\psi)$ and $a(\psi')$ (anti)-commute (depending on the statistics). An other way to see this, as OP pointed out, is to see that the change of basis is of the form $$b_\mu = \sum_{\lambda} \alpha_{\mu,\lambda} a_{\lambda}$$ i.e. it is linear in annihilation operators.
There is a more general kind of linear transformation possible on a Fock space, called a Bogoliubov transformation. This is a transformation linear in both creation and annihilation operators :
$$b_\mu = \sum_{\lambda} \alpha_{\mu,\lambda} a_{\lambda}+\beta_{\mu,\lambda}a^\dagger_\lambda$$
(with some constraints on the coefficients, to ensure that the commutation relations are preserved).
Then, the vacuum (and more generally $n$-particle subspaces) are not preserved. This has physical implications in various contexts, from Hawking radiation to superfluidity and quantum optics.

It is evident linear algebra. Intuition? Try a space of just two bosonic oscillators, i=1,2,
$$
[a_i,a^\dagger_j]=\delta_{ij}, \qquad [a_i,a_j]=0, 
$$ and ditto for the conjugates.
Rotate them to
$$
\tilde a_1=\cos\theta ~ a_1+ \sin\theta ~ a_2=\sum_k\langle k|\tilde 1\rangle a_k,\\
\tilde a_2=\cos\theta ~ a_2- \sin\theta ~ a_1=\sum_k\langle k|\tilde 2\rangle a_k,
$$
and ditto for the conjugates.
It is then evident that
$$
[\tilde a_i,\tilde a_j]=0, \qquad [\tilde a_i,  a_j]=0,
$$
and ditto for the conjugates, as well as
$$
[\tilde a_i,\tilde a_j^\dagger ]=\delta_{ij}, \qquad [ a_i, \tilde a_j^\dagger]=\langle i|\tilde j\rangle.
$$
